# Firebase functions v2 and traffic allocation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Is there a way to manage traffic allocation during deployment of Firebase 2nd gen cloud functions? When you deploy with Cloud Run, you can specify tag and --no-traffic, but not with Firebase CLI. In my case, I'd like a staged rollout with partial traffic allocation.